# virtuemart pdf invoice not generate

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I am using joomla 3.4.1 and virtuemart 3.0.9.
When order place in site it generate invoice in mail which is HTML mail.
I need pdf copy with attachment in that mail.Is it any configuration for this functionality for this ? Or any customization require for this.

Please give me the answer of that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Invoice creation depends on order status and could be configured under:

```
Configuration -> Checkout -> Default Order Status to create an invoice
```

Comment: I have set already of that status settings in configuration and i am getting mail of orders.

Comment: I am getting html mail and i need to pdf copy of that invoice when order status is confirmed by shopper.

Comment: I have already install virtuemart-aio package as well as tcpdf component.

Comment: Please double check that you have added the order status to this field.

Comment: When i have place order my order status will be store in database like "Confirm by shopper" and i have set invoice create status also "Confirm by shopper".